# How to keep a task running after the main thread ends?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have an application that runs every 15 minutes. I need to add a new task (Maybe a Method) which will be called by the application and should run asynchronously, so the application can complete within the 15 Minutes. If the new task takes longer than the application is running, it will be aborted and can't complete its work. How can I keep a Task running?

Comment: Wait for its completion on the main thread?

Comment: What happens if in the next run the previous haven't been completed yet? Should it run anyway, should it not run or should it wait for the previous run to end before it starts?

Comment: The idiomatic way is async main language feature introduced in C# 7.1: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-async-main-in-c-sharp-7-1/

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That would restrain the main thread to finish within the 15 minutes.

Comment: @Magnetron It should wait for the previous run to end before the new one starts. But the additional Task should not slow down the main application.

Comment: How do you run the application every 15 minutes? Have you scheduled it's execution through the Windows Task Scheduler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you can go about this.

#### Independent process

The first is, don't run a task, run an independent process that can do the work. The first process will end when it needs to; the worker process will end when it needs to, and there's no communication between them (unless there needs to be for a different reason).

```
// in main thread...
var process = new Process(); // create the process
...
process.Start();
// process.WaitForExit(); this is commented out because you want main process to end without waiting
// main then ends here
```

Now the above means creating two separate executables; one for the launcher and one for the worker. That means two separate projects... or not.

What you can do is have both sets of functionality in the same executable, and invoke the functionality you need by separating it with command-line arguments. In your main you could do:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   if (args.Length == 1 && args[0] == "worker")
      DoWorkerStuff();
   else
   {
      var process = new Process(); // create the process
      ...
      // use process API to call yourself with the arg
      process.Start();
      // process.WaitForExit(); this is commented out because you want main process to end without waiting
   }

    // main then ends here for both the launcher and the worker
}
```

I like this approach because you have full isolation due to process boundaries, and yet you don't have to compile and maintain separate projects.

#### Wait on the main thread

The second way is for the main thread to wait until the worker task is done. Trying to have tasks outlive the main thread can be problematic. Waiting is easy

```
    // in main thread...
    var task = ... // however you create the task
    ...
    task.Wait(); // or one of the other Wait() overloads
```

There are, of course, other ways to start background work (e.g. using `Thread`) and for ways for the background work to signal the main thread, but these all require that original thread to wait until the work is done.

Comment: The own process would be a good solution. But is there a way, not to add an additional .exe? Like I would need to call an external .exe file right? Or can I execute code from a method in the main process?
The second solution would restrain the main process to finish :/

Comment: Thank you, no I understand the concept :) But sadly I have no idea how to implement this // use process API to call yourself with the arg